# Preload certain area to avoid lags in google maps due to loading of tiles

Tags: android, google-maps, camera

I am displaying an are of about 15km x 15km in a Google Map v2 in Android. In this area i have about 20 objects, displayed as markers. By clicking buttons the user can center the map on the different objects. This is achieved by animating the camera of the map to the position of the object.

However this is stuttering and insanely laggy due to google maps loading the map data (streetnames, background) while animating the camera to the next object.

Since it looks really *really* bad to have the camera stutter like this on a high end smartphone my question is this:

Is there a possibility to "preload" this 15 x 15 km area so that the animations can run smoothly over map content cached in memory?

Or is there another way to prevent the camera animations from stuttering?

Since all user interaction takes place in this 15 x 15km area there is no need for reloading all map data whenever the camera is animated.

Thanks a lot for all help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to have map data preloaded when using Google Maps Android API v2.

The data is only cached on SD when user goes into that region.

You may also try using a different map provider.